# Can Transmission get damaged While the Car is in Neutral While parking Brake is on?

Tags: transmission, parking-brake

Can transmission get damaged while the car is in neutral while the brake is ON ??

Does towing damage the E-Brake ?

Let's say the towing distance is 20 Meters?

Comment: Automatic transmission?

Answer (score 2):

> Can Transmission get damaged While the Car is in Neutral While the Brake is ON ??

Under normal conditions, no.

> Does Towing Damage the E-Brake ?

Only if it's on while the vehicle is moving. The longer it's on, the more damage occurs.

> Lets say The Towing Distance is 20 Meters

See above.

Comment: 20 kilometers would do some damage (wear out the brakes a bit), 20 meters would do 1000 times less damage.

Comment: So Keeping E-Brake on or off have no impact what so over on the transmission ??

Comment: "So Keeping E-Brake on or off have no impact what so over on the transmission" No